# Как отцентровать Flex- блок с картинками в адаптивной верстке? Верстка проходит кросс-браузерность, но адаптивность нет

Tags: flexbox

В браузерах все по центру. Много див`ов, опыта работы с флекс немного. А при подгоне под тот же pixel2 блок уходит влево(скриншот приложен)[image: тот самый скриншот]

```css
///браузерный код///
.par-container{
 
 
  display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
}
  .flex-container {
  display: flex;
    width: 800px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 
    
  }
  .part1 {
   display: flex;
    align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
  }
  .part2 {
   display: flex;
    align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
  }
  

 
#per img {
 display: flex;
  align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
 flex-basis: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="par-container">
<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="part1">
<div id="per">
<img  class="razmerf" src="images/ex1.jpg" alt="img">

</div>
<div id="per">
<img  class="razmerf" src="images/ex2.jpg" alt="img">
</div>
<div id="per">
<img class="razmerf"  src="images/ex3.jpg"  alt="img">
</div>
</div>
 <div class="part2">
<div id="per">
<img class="razmerf"  src="images/ex4.jpg"  alt="img">
</div>
<div id="per">
<img class="razmerf"  src="images/ex5.jpg"  alt="img">
</div>
<div id="per">
<img class="razmerf"  src="images/ex6.jpg"  alt="img">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
///медиа-запрос///
@media  screen 
and (min-device-width : 411px) 
and (max-device-width : 731px) {////pixel2
.par-container{
 
   
  display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
}
  
   
   .flex-container {
  display: flex;
    width: 400px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
   .part1 {
   display: flex;
    align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
  }
  .part2 {
   display: flex;
    align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
  }
#per img {
 display: flex;
  align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
 flex-basis: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 
 }
 
  

    
    }
```

Comment: @peter/// именно многократное использование #per собрало 6 картин в прямоугольный блок. Без присвоения картинкам id они при разных разрешениях экрана вели себя по-разному. А если id всем разные обозначаешь, начинается вообще несуразица.

Comment: @peter/// понятно, спасибо